# Uglifyjs overwrite file

Tags: uglifyjs

I'm having trouble trying to overwrite the file that has been uglified. Unfortunately, I can't output to a different file name.

Here are some of the attempts:

`uglifyjs dist/main.*.js --compress drop_console=true --overwrite`

`find ./dist -name "main.*.js" | xargs uglifyjs --compress drop_console=true --overwrite file`

`find ./dist -name "main.*.js" | xargs uglifyjs -f --compress drop_console=true --overwrite file -o file`

Each time it just prints to STDOUT. If I do something like `uglifyjs dist/main.*.js --compress drop_console=true -o main.min.js` it will work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: not an answer, but I was running this using npm. I just created another npm script right after, that grep | sed the index.html and replaced the main.*.bundle.js with the outputed uglifyjs file - main.min.js

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following command for uglify multiple files at once. The `maxdepth` option is there for ignoring `node_modules` directory.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.js" -exec uglifyjs --compress --mangle -o {}.min -- {} \;
```

The command is just an example, it outputs a *.min file for every *.js file, but you can use a different function for naming output files. If you want to output to the same file just use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.js" -exec uglifyjs --compress --mangle -o {} -- {} \;
```